# Using the same private network address ranges on all routers

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, modem

My setup: 2 desktops (Desk1 and Desk2) and 1 laptop (Laptop1).  Both desktops are plugged into the back of my AT&T      BGW210-700 modem/router.  I also have a Linksys EA9300 wireless router connected to the modem, which Laptop1 connects to.  The modem hands out IPs in the 192.168.1.x range- Desk1 is 192.168.1.67 and Desk2 is 192.168.1.75.  The Linksys shows up as 192.168.1.79 on the modem's device list.  Laptop1 doesn't show up at all on the modem.  According to the Linksys, its IP is 10.25.142.4, and Laptop1 is 10.25.142.83.

I share files across my computers, and all I have to do from, say, Desk1 is go to `\\Desk2\[folder]` in explorer. However, I can't reach Laptop1 the same way because it's behind the Linksys.  Laptop1 can still see and access both desktops.  I also use Ultra VNC to control the desktops and laptop from any of them, and the situation is the same: Laptop1 can control both desktops, but neither desktop can control Laptop1.  Is there a way to have all devices, even those attached to the Linksys, assigned a 192.168.1.x IP so they can all talk to each other?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else has a similar situation, the answer is very simple: I set the Linksys router to bridge mode.  Now it acquires IPs from the AT&T modem for all devices connected to it (instead of assigning them itself), and they are all 192.168.1.x.  Also, in order for other computers on the network to see my laptop, I had to change the network profile to private- I guess Windows sets networks as public automatically for security.  Now all devices see each other.